# Getting null on account/verify_credentials using package abraham/twitteroauth

Tags: laravel, twitter-oauth

I have a free account on Twitter developer portal. On the developer portal I got the consumer key and secret the access token and secret as well.

but when I call:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey,$consumerSecret,$access_token,$access_token_secret);

$content = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
dd($content);
```

I get `null`. Can anyone please explain me why is that?

Comment: I believe you are doing that when you create the oauth object. assuming you are using the same package I am looking at the consumer is created and that does that for you. You should just be able to make request, I think.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you had any luck fixing this? I get the same issue